# Using LocationManager from another class than Main

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

i'm new here,
i'm new in iphone development,
i'm new in Objective-c
and i'm new in engligh speaking, so don't hate me :P

I'm creating an application that will use the location manager to display the distance between the own position and the positions of a list of shops, like AroundME.

Now, i give the locationManager property to my main class and in the .m of that class, precisely in the viewDidLoad method, i make: [locationManager startUpdatingLocation].

It all works fine, but the problem is:
i need to know my position in other classes than the main, but i don't think that is a good idea making [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] every time i need it, is not time overhead?

The view of my main class is always below the others, so can i retrieve the updated location in my other classes? In what way?

Creating another instance of my main class is not useful, i think, but the locationManager, once started, doesn't stop until my main class is released, isn't true? So i think that it is accessible in some way.

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my awful english : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you set your main class as the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in this case. Your delegate will receive `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` messages when the location is updated and in that method you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to post messages which instances of other classes can add themselves as observers for.  See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSNotificationCenter` for more info on adding observers and posting notifications.

To get the initial location in other classes besides main, you'll probably have to have a reference to the main class and retrieve it using the `location` property of `CLLocationManager` because your observers will only receive notifications when the location has changed.